# Netbeans 8.2 doesn't suggest elements from my Library/JAR

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

I added a JAR file with many libraries to my Project but then when I write `import org.` and cick `Ctrl + spacebar` NetBeans 8.2 suggests me some packages but not those that are in that library. But if I write exactly the class I need, NetBeans is ok with it.

[This is the JAR I added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwr5O.png)

[This shows how NetBeans 8.2 doesn't recognize the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82dzW.png)

This problem doesn't occur on NetBeans 8.1

I have tried to add the JAR in many ways after research but nothing solved the problem

Comment: Having this issue too, have you managed to find a fix for it?